# Using Codeception with Wordpress: During page load an outside http request is made, how do i check the response of that request?

Tags: wordpress, codeception

I'm using Codeception/WP Browser to write tests for Wordpress. I had a method on a class that was making an outside http request whenever it was being loaded up and this was incorrect behavior. It's only supposed to make that request on a certain page, and on others it is not. I have rewritten the code so its fixed, but I dont know how to go about testing it. I've tried loading up the acceptance, functional and wpunit tester helpers but none of them seem to have anything that lets me grab a response from an outside http request on page load. Can anyone help?

Ive tried using the different modules, but I cant seem to find the magic combination or I am just lost.

heres some of my acceptance code that isnt doing it

```php
<?php
// $ codecept run acceptance exampleExpectLoginByAdminCest

class expectLoginByAdminCest {

    public function _before( AcceptanceTester $I ) {
    }
    public function _after( AcceptanceTester $I ) {
    }

    public function expectsAdminToLogin( AcceptanceTester $I ) {
        // ARRANGE
        $I->wantTo( 'log in as an Admin' );
        $I->amGoingTo( 'log in as Admin' );
        // ACT
        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPage( "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=advisor-dashboard&course=8927" );
        // ASSERT
        // tokens shouldnt be available so bad response
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(401);
    }
}
```

Heres a copy of my acceptance config

```
# Suite for acceptance tests.
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WPDb
        - WPWebDriver
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        WPDb:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=%TEST_SITE_DB_HOST%;dbname=%TEST_SITE_DB_NAME%'
            user: '%TEST_SITE_DB_USER%'
            password: '%TEST_SITE_DB_PASSWORD%'
            dump: 'tests/_data/rwa-dump.sql'
            #import the dump before the tests; this means the test site database will be repopulated before the tests.
            populate: true
            # re-import the dump between tests; this means the test site database will be repopulated between the tests.
            cleanup: true
            waitlock: 10
            url: '%TEST_SITE_WP_URL%'
            urlReplacement: true #replace the hardcoded dump URL with the one above
            tablePrefix: '%TEST_SITE_TABLE_PREFIX%'
        WPWebDriver:
            url: '%CHROMEDRIVER_WP_URL%'
            adminUsername: 'admin'
            adminPassword: 'admin'
            adminPath: '/wp-admin'
            browser: chrome
            host: %CHROMEDRIVER_HOST%
            port: %CHROMEDRIVER_PORT%
            capabilities:
                # Used in more recent releases of Selenium.
                "goog:chromeOptions":
                    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--user-agent=wp-browser"]
                    w3c: false
                # Support the old format for back-compatibility purposes.
                "chromeOptions":
                    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--user-agent=wp-browser"]
                    w3c: false
```

The api call should fail, and get a 401 because no token should be available to authenticate, but its getting a 200

Comment: How is the request being made? I assume it's in a $(document).ready() or similar callback? Could you set something on the Javascript window object when the request is sent and assert the presence or absence of that property in your test?

Comment: I went a different route with this, and I'm a lot closer now. The request was being made through the php using wordpresses: `wp_remote_request`. Instead of trying to use a functional or acceptance test I went back to using a wpunit test and installed https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock - mocked out my class and then loaded the template file